# Live Streaming using WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, live-streaming

Currently I'm working on a project to stream live video content from the WP8 Camera to `FFserver`.

I was able to capture the video feed in a file ,but was unable to find a way to pass the camera feed to a server.

In the previous streaming applications that I created for other platforms I was able to use `FFmpeg` profusely to stream content to the server by compiling platform dependent binaries and then using `ffmpeg-cli` to accomplish the task.

But in the case of WP* it seems to have no NDK or toolchain to compile `ffmpeg` libraries.

Is there any way to accomplish the task of streaming live video to server using WP8?